# Unexpected Error in Synapse Datflow- XX column is not of the same unpivot datatype

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I wanna unpivot column in Synapse dataflow, but the debug was not worked due to below error.
[image: the error message]

The error says "XX column is not of the same unpivot datatype", but I select the correct datatype.
Before unpivot, datatype of columns that I wanna unpivot is all decimal.
[image: Unpivot Setting]

As you can see the column datatype is all Decimal, so I'm confused...
[image: The data before unpivot]

The deadline of this task is imminent and I am in a hurry.
Any answer would be helped.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same thing with all decimal column which we want to unpivot and got similar error.

[image]

sample data:

[image]

To resolve this, **you have to mention all columns other than decimal data type has to be mentioned in `Ungroup by`** .

[image]

Output:

[image]